Landlord knowingly charges a smaller amount than originally discussed. Is tenant obligated in the difference?
A tenant enters into an agreement for a short term lease, let's say 6 months at $3000 a month. The landlord requires payment through an online portal, to which they post the charges every month and the tenant submits a payment. The first month, tenant notices that the charge is only $100. Tenant pays $3000 in good faith, assuming a clerical error that will be corrected. Portal now shows a credit for the tenant in the amount of $2900.
The next month, charges in the portal are again $100. It automatically gets applied to the credit, so the portal now shows a credit to the tenant in the amount of $2800. Tenant emails landlord asking about the online charges, landlord responds that they will look into it and follow up. They never do, tenant moves out at the end of the term with a total of $600 charged against the first payment of $3000.
Is there any law or precedent to suggest something like the tenant does not owe any further payment, it's as though the landlord agreed to the new charge amount, as the landlord knowingly charged only a nominal amount?
Location is in New Jersey, USA.

If the Tenant was able to pay $3000 the 1st month despite the online portal only showing $100 due, then what would have prevented the Tenant from continuing to pay $3000 per month for the balance of the lease term (and observing the credit amount rising by a steady $2900 per month)?

AFAIK the tenant owes the landlord, but debts can expire. Another point is what did happen to the $2400 remaining at the payment processor. Did the tenant recover it? It's it available only to the landlord?

@brhans fair point, but the tenant could argue that the unexpected behaviour of the system made him cautious before putting more money. That they did warn the landlord would support that POV.

In New-Jersey, The tenant has the sole responsibility to pay the rent amount

A tenant has the responsibility to pay the full amount of rent on time.

As well, a landlord can't force payments to be through electronic means, so a failure to pay rent due to a platform failure would probably not change anything for the tenant.

Even if the landlord isn’t charging the correct amount?

@JoeW Almost certainly. This is obviously a mistake in setting up the billing amount, but the contract takes precedence.

How is it a mistake in setting up the billing amount of the tenant reaches out to the landlord about the mistake and the landlord responds saying that they will look into it? At that point it seems like the error is entirely on the landlords side.

@JoeW I am pretty sure you can sue for unpaid rent a long bit after the lease is up, that would be a defense for the tenant, but at the end of the day, What is written (or agreed upon) always takes precendence

You are saying that the landlord can knowingly charge an incorrect amount, make no effort to collect the correct amount and would still have no blame in this? It sounds like the landlord setup the payment amount, was told it was wrong, acknowledged it was wrong but did nothing to correct it. Even if they had attempted to pay the full amount the system would not let them do it.

@JoeW I don't know the specifics of NJ law and what a judge would rule on that, but by black and white law, the tenant is responsible

The tenant is responsible for the landlord not accepting the full payment?

@JoeW The tenant is responsible for paying the amount in full, if the online portal is malfunctioning, then you can mail a check.... Again, it would sure be a plausible defense if that ever went to trial, and I have no idea what would a judge rule

It sounds like the portal is the only way to pay as the landlord requires payment through that portal. And it sure sounds like the landlord is refusing to correct the issue that was pointed out to them and acknowledged. The online portal is not malfunctioning rather the landlord doesn't have it setup correctly to bill the full amount.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
